# Bash : `[0-9]+$` Regular Expression is not working to match exclusively 3-digit numbers

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have executed below code to check if field "eid" is having length 3 digit and all are digit -

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

input="A01#PoonamSahani#IVS#123456"

#recCount=`echo $input | awk -F "#" '{print NF}'`

eid=`echo $input | cut -d "#" -f 1`
ename=`echo $input | cut -d "#" -f 2`
dept=`echo $input | cut -d "#" -f 3`
salary=`echo $input | cut -d "#" -f 4`

if [[ ${#eid} == 3 && $eid =~ [0-9]+$ ]]
then
        echo "$eid"
else
        echo "Check"
fi
```

After execution getting below output -

```
root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~# ./3ex.sh 
A01
```

Please advise what is missing here?

Comment: Note that this is really, really not something you should be doing as root. Running as root means a minor bug in your script could break your entire system (a bad `rm` command, for example). Please don't do development as root!

Answer (score 10):

You have already found a better approach, but your script is still very inefficient since it needs to manipulate the input 4 separate times. There's no need for that, you can do it in a single step:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

input="A01#PoonamSahani#IVS#123456"

read -d '#' eid ename dept salary <<<"$input"

if [[ ${#eid} == 3 && $eid =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
        echo "$eid"
else
        echo "Check"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to use `^` at the start:

```
if [[ ${#eid} == 3 && $eid =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

Comment: You could also have used `if [[ $input =~ ^[0-9]{3}# ]]; then ...` to get rid of those `echo`+`cut` pipelines.